# The left column and right column shifts in Joomla

Tags: css, joomla

I am running website in Joomla 1.5 .
I have a webpage [here](http://www.jklinks.com/entertainment/movies/movie/188640.html)

Its working perfectly . If you select Director Sanjay Gupta on this page it disorted. The similar links are giving me the problem. I am not able to figure put the problem . Although I know its css problme. can you please help me or give me hint to adjust it.

the distorted page link is [here](http://www.jklinks.com/entertainment/movies/person/114922.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this:

```
#ja-content #ja-col1{
    padding-left: 50px;
    width:auto;
    float:none;
}
```

At least it fixes the problem for me

Comment: But I have `#ja-col1{float:left;overflow:hidden;width:20%}
#ja-col2{float:right;overflow:hidden;width:20%}` in my css . What to change and how will I replace the previous with your code

Comment: do not replace anything, just add my code at the end of the CSS file which is /templates/ja_trona/css/template.css